# Getting two digit month and date from DateTime in perl

Tags: perl, datetime

Hello I am using Perl's DateTime to parse a string and convert it to a date format.

My code here looks like this:

```
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time_zone => 'UTC', on_error  => 'croak');
my $startDate = $parser->parse_datetime("2017-04-14T21:00:00Z");
my $endDate = $parser->parse_datetime("2017-04-14T23:00:00Z");
print $startDate->month();
```

When I print the month, I get only 4, or if the date is changed to a number less than 10, I get a single digit number.

Is there a cleaner way to obtain the two digit month/date without prepending a zero before the number if its less than 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use sprintf (or printf, if you're just going to print it).

```
my $month = sprintf("%02d", $startDate->month());
```

It will zero-pad your input. Take a look at [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to learn more about the format parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Can also get all of them, as you'll probably need them

```
my ($year, $mon, $day) = unpack "A4A2A2", $startDate->ymd('');
```

or

```
my ($year, $mon, $day) = split /-/, $startDate->ymd();
```

The default separator for [DateTime::ymd](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DROLSKY/DateTime-1.44/lib/DateTime.pm#$dt-%3Eymd(-$optional_separator-),-$dt-%3Emdy(...),-$dt-%3Edmy(...)) is `-` (dash).

Both these methods yield two-digit month and day.